# MongoError: pool destroyed when fetching all data without conditions

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mlab

I am new to mongoDb, as I am trying to query from different collection and in order to do that, when I am fetching data from category collection I mean when I am running select * from collection it is throwing error, MongoError: pool destroyed.

As per my understanding it is because of some find({}) is creating a pool and that is being destroyed.

The code which I am using inside model is below,

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const dbConfig = require('../configurations/database.config.js');

export const getAllCategoriesApi = (req, res, next) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject ) => {
    let finalCategory = []
    const client = new MongoClient(dbConfig.url, { useNewUrlParser: true });
    client.connect(err => {

      const collection = client.db(dbConfig.db).collection("categories");
      debugger
      if (err) throw err;
      let query = { CAT_PARENT: { $eq: '0' } };
      collection.find(query).toArray(function(err, data) {
        if(err) return next(err);
        finalCategory.push(data);
        resolve(finalCategory);
        // db.close();
      });
      client.close();
    });
  });
}
```

When my finding here is when I am using

let query = { CAT_PARENT: { $eq: '0' } };
collection.find(query).toArray(function(err, data) {})

When I am using find(query) it is returning data but with {} or $gte/gt it is throwing Pool error.

The code which I have written in controller is below,

```
import { getAllCategoriesListApi } from '../models/fetchAllCategory';
const redis = require("redis");
const client = redis.createClient(process.env.REDIS_PORT);

export const getAllCategoriesListData = (req, res, next, query) => {

  // Try fetching the result from Redis first in case we have it cached
  return client.get(`allstorescategory:${query}`, (err, result) => {
    // If that key exist in Redis store
    if (false) {
      res.send(result)
    } else { 
      // Key does not exist in Redis store
      getAllCategoriesListApi(req, res, next).then( function ( data ) {
        const responseJSON = data;
        // Save the Wikipedia API response in Redis store
        client.setex(`allstorescategory:${query}`, 3600, JSON.stringify({ source: 'Redis Cache', responseJSON }));
        res.send(responseJSON)
      }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err)
      })
    }
  });
}
```

Can any one tell me what mistake I am doing here. How I can fix pool issue. 
Thanking you in advance.

Comment: What is your driver version?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `toArray` is asynchronous (i.e. it invokes the callback passed in as results become available, i.e. read from the network).

If this is true the `client.close();` call is going to get executed prior to results having been read, hence likely yielding your error.

The `close` call needs to be done after you have finished iterating the results.

Separately from this, you should probably not be creating the client instance in the request handler like this. Client instances are expensive to create (they must talk to all of the servers in the deployment before they can actually perform queries) and generally should be created per running process rather than per request.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion, can you give me some more insight about your second statement, I didnt get it.

Comment: Are you asking what it means for javascript to be asynchronous?